# Do Java Mail APIs cache sent/tobesent emails?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm using Java Mail APIs to send email from the code without using external SMTP servers. I'd like to understand if Java uses some local cache to store mails ready to be sent or already sent.

If yes (or if it's configurable) how to set/enable/disable/configure it?

Thank you in advance

Davide

Answer (score 0):

No, JavaMail does not "cache" or "queue" messages waiting to be sent.  JavaMail expects to be able to talk to an SMTP server (which can be local) and hands the message off to it to be queued for delivery.